# Trigger a plot shape or alert only when the trend changes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
buysignal = (close > vwap) and (close > ema24)  
sellsignal = (close < vwap) and (close < ema24)

// draw some shapes on the chart if conditions are met
plotshape(buysignal, title = 'long', style=shape.triangleup, size=size.normal, text='up')
plotshape(sellsignal, title = 'short', style =shape.triangledown, size=size.normal, text='down')

// create alert conditions!
alertcondition(buysignal, title="Buy-Signal", message="bull")
alertcondition(sellsignal, title="Sell-Signal", message="bear")
```

I have written some code like the above to identify trend. Can you please help me figure out, how do I trigger a plot shape or alert only when the trend changes from bull to bear or vice versa and not for every candle close? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the previous state with the current state. Then you that in your functions.

```
is_new_buy_signal = not buysignal[1] and buysignal
```